# update query in Windows Azure Mobile Service javascript/html

Tags: javascript, azure-mobile-services

Am using HTML/javascript to connect to my mobile web service .

the select query is working fine without issues and the connection done ,now I want to update one row. The updating is not working in my html page, no error Alerting.the last alert line not reached .  I need to update the status to "2"
This is my javascript

```
    var TimeListTable = client.getTable('Match_Times');

                            // 
    TimeListTable.update({
                                id: "2",
                                status: "2"
                            }).read().done(function (result) {
                                alert("updating done")
                            }, function (err) {
                                alert("Error: " + err);
                            });

    alert("reach here")
```

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the problem ,, It was wrong to send string id , replacing id: "2" -> id: 2 will fix it and it works . Also I made it simple and it works

```
var TimeListTable = client.getTable('Match_Times');

TimeListTable.update({
                    id: 2,
                    status: "2"
                });

alert("reach here")
```

Comment: FYI, your `alert` call will be executed regardless of whether the update succeeds or fails. If you want it to be executed only after it's done, you should do it in the `done` call as you were doing in your original post.

Answer (score 0):

There's an issue with your command (there's actually a bug just like this in one of the tutorials, which should be fixed soon, I'm guessing you got it from there): there should be no `.read()` call after the `update` call. Try changing your code to this, and it should work:

```
TimeListTable.update({
    id: "2",
    status: "2"
}).done(function (result) {
    alert("updating done");
}, function (err) {
    alert("Error: " + err);
});
```

Comment: I fixed it in the answer below ,The mistake was using string id instead of integer